# How do I enable a disk template in Ganeti?

Tags: ganeti

I want to create a virtual machine with an RBD volume for storage. However, when I run the relevant `gnt-instance add -t rbd ...` incantation, I get:

```
Failure: prerequisites not met for this operation:
Disk template 'rbd' is not enabled in cluster. Enabled disk templates are ...
```

How can I enable disk templates?

*Full disclosure: I am paid to work on Ganeti.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass *two* parameters to `gnt-group` modify:

```
gnt-cluster modify --ipolicy-disk-templates full,list,of,needed,disk,templates \
                   --enabled-disk-templates full,list,of,needed,disk,templates
```

So if you have `plain` and `drbd` already enabled and you *also* wanted `rbd`, you would run this:

```
gnt-cluster modify --enabled-disk-templates plain,rbd,drbd
                   --ipolicy-disk-templates plain,rbd,drbd
```

Conversely this command enables `shared-file` *only*, disabling everything else in the process:

```
gnt-cluster modify --enabled-disk-templates shared-file
                   --ipolicy-disk-templates shared-file
```

---

Why repeat the list twice? What's the difference between the two switches?

Say that, for some reason, you have a Ganeti group `alpha` that should only have `rbd` instances and a Ganeti group `bravo` that should only have `drbd` instances. You can enforce that like so:

```
gnt-cluster modify --enabled-disk-templates rbd,drbd \
                   --ipolicy-disk-templates rbd,drbd;
gnt-group   modify --ipolicy-disk-templates rbd      alpha;
gnt-group   modify --ipolicy-disk-templates     drbd bravo;
```

There are a number of constraints to keep in mind in order to keep invariants true:

- ipolicy can't allow disabled disk templates.
- you can't disable or disallow disk templates in use.

If you only have the `default` group this feature is not very useful, but it has to be set anyway.